# Javascript Styling Link

Tags: javascript

First disclosure: I have a lot of scripts running on this particular page.

I have a div of text that I have on page load, now there is a specific link which is toggled to this text, based on clicking on the link. WHEN the page is loaded, I want just the link to be a certain color.

Here is what I have for the text so far... which is displaying on pageload:

```
<script>
     window.onload=function showDiv() {
     document.getElementById('d1').style.display = "block";
      }
     </script>
```

**Now I need to have my link a specific color on page load, but that color must be able to change back to its CSS default when another link is clicked:**

```
<a href="javascript:unhide('d1');" onClick="changeLinkColor(this)">Innovative Design Methodology</a>
```

Like I said, there are other scripts I have running on this page, hence you see in the link.

Just for fun, here's my other code (toggling text & highlighting code):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentItem;
function unhide(divID) {
    if (currentItem) {
        currentItem.className = 'hidden';
        currentItem = null;
    }
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
        item.className = 'unhidden';
        currentItem = item;
    }
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var currentLink = null;
        function changeLinkColor(link){
            if(currentLink!=null){
                currentLink.style.color = link.style.color; 
            }
            link.style.color = '#f5b331';
            currentLink = link;
        }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a css class on the anchor tag initially (which has your custom styling) and remove it on click on any of the links.

Your HTML

```
<a id="link1" class='CustomColor'></a>
```

And your CSS

```
.CustomColor
{
    color:red;
}
```

And On click of any link,

```
document.getElementById("link1").className =
document.getElementById("link1").className.replace('CustomColor','');
```

Comment: Beat me to it :) You forgot the dot before the class decleration